# Magento upgrade from 2.4.0 to 2.4.1 Cannot allocate memory Error

Tags: upgrade, memory-limit

I´m with a 4Gb RAM with 1Gb SWAP at Cloudways and try to upgrade my Magento from 2.4.0 to 2.4.1 following this procedure: https://forums.envato.com/t/how-to-upgrade-magento-version-from-2-4-0-to-2-4-1/340406

For that I installed and use Composer 1.
My PHP configuration are with 4Gb limit, and 6000s limit time.

After run composer update I'm receiving this erros bellow.
Any ideia how can I solve that?

Thank you!

> public_html$ /home/master/composer update Loading composer
> repositories with package information Warning from
> https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of
> Composer. Composer 2 is now available and you should upgrade. See
> https://getcomposer.org/2 Updating dependencies (including
> require-dev) Package operations: 19 installs, 270 updates, 6 removals
>
> - Removing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1) Removing Psr/SimpleCache
> - Removing league/mime-type-detection (1.5.1) Removing League/MimeTypeDetection
> - Removing league/flysystem (1.1.3) Removing League/Flysystem
> - Removing doctrine/inflector (v1.1.0) Removing Doctrine/Inflector
> - Removing doctrine/cache (1.10.2) Removing Doctrine/Cache
> - Removing cache/cache (0.4.0) Removing Cache/Cache
> - Updating symfony/process (v4.4.16 => v4.4.20): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.20.0 => v1.22.1): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.20.0 => v1.22.1): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.20.0 => v1.22.1): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating symfony/console (v4.4.16 => v4.4.20): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.20.0 => v1.22.1): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating symfony/finder (v5.1.8 => v5.2.4): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating symfony/filesystem (v5.1.8 => v5.2.4): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating seld/jsonlint (1.8.2 => 1.8.3): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating composer/xdebug-handler (1.4.4 => 1.4.5): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating composer/spdx-licenses (1.5.4 => 1.5.5): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating composer/semver (1.7.1 => 1.7.2): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating composer/ca-bundle (1.2.8 => 1.2.9): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating composer/composer (1.10.6 => 1.10.19): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating magento/magento-composer-installer (0.1.13 => 0.2.0): Downloading (100%)
> - Updating magento/composer-root-update-plugin (1.0.0 => 1.1.0): Downloading (100%)          Installing
>   "magento/composer-root-update-plugin: 1.1.0" for the Web Setup Wizard
>   Loading composer repositories with package information Warning from
>   https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of
>   Composer. Composer 2 is now available and you should upgrade. See
>   https://getcomposer.org/2 Updating dependencies Package operations: 24
>   installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
> - Installing react/promise (v2.8.0): Downloading (100%)
>   proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory
>   The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
>   Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class Web Setup Wizard installation of "magento/composer-root-update-plugin:
>   1.1.0" failed proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory
> - Updating magento/module-ui (101.2.0 => 101.2.1): The following exception is caused by a lack of memory or swap, or not having swap
>   configured Check
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors
>   for details
>
> PHP Warning:  proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in
> phar:///home/master/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on
> line 952
>
> Warning: proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in
> phar:///home/master/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on
> line 952
> [ErrorException]                                      proc_open():
> fork failed - Cannot allocate memory
>
> update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
> [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader]
> [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies]
> [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
> [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
> [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable]
> [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--]
> []...
>
> (failed reverse-i-search)`': composer ^Cearcache

Comment: I restart the server and did the update.
Everything goes fine.

Anyone nows if I can use the same procedure to goes to 2.4.2?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general warning of the composer. Once the composer is self-updated, the issue will be resolved.
Run the below command: composer self-update